# TV pseudo-documentary featuring a flooded Earth and floating city

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for a TV pseudo documentary, from around 200x-201x. I watched it on cable, possibly Discovery Channel. The title may be similar to "water world" (the movie, I know)

- A giant ice comet crashed with our Moon or passed Earth's Roche limit, forming a ring system around Earth.
- These ice meteorites periodically come down, rise the sea level. And whenever a bigger piece falls down, a huge Tsunami formed, wreaking havoc around the world.
- As the result, governments around the world start various plans to combat this situation.
- Micronesia islands were gone first, created a refugee crisis.
- The EU's plan is building a very high wall around their cities. But one failed catastrophically (a Spanish city I think), as the wall cannot be built high enough, created a huge number of death.
- The US has 2 plans, one is moving higher inland (there could be a scene showing Hollywood Hills with a lot of refugees tent?). Another is build floating cities. Those cities are not one big structure, but a collection of smaller modules.
- There is a talk about the floating cities being vulnerable to Tsunami, feature [FLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP_FLIP)

I watched only the first episode, so I can only remember this much.
I tried to google it with "floating city documentary", "ice comet strike", "flooded earth" to no avail.

Comment: *[Discover Channel: Earth Under Water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jrp9cFjuYnM)*? Shows lots of flooded cities. The end talks about floating cities

Comment: Not submitting this as an answer as I can't provide any details but maybe this will help somebody identify it. There was a documentary series a few years ago about six different ways the world could end - one of them was flooding because of a ring of ice around the Earth which meant it rained for decades. I remember the wall being built around a Spanish city but there was a structural failure and the water got in.
I think another episode in the series had self-replicating nanobots escaping from a military installation.

Comment: @GordonD - This one? https://tv.apple.com/gb/show/doomsday-10-ways-the-world-will-end/umc.cmc.6awnuli72ghzske6ihi5ekaop

Comment: Just wanted to say welcome and great first question!

Comment: @Valorum - It's the same idea but that isn't the one. Neither the nanobots nor the worldwide flooding (as asked by the OP) are included.

Comment: @GordonD Yes that series! I also remember the nanobot one. I'll check if I can find anything use that clue.

Comment: @Valorum I read the review of that show. Unfortunately there is a flooding scenario but not from a ice comet which is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure *[Evacuate Earth](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evacuate_Earth)* on NatGeo is the answer.

> Evacuate Earth is a National Geographic Channel documentary that portrays the hypothetical scenario of humans evacuating the planet Earth before it is destroyed by a rogue neutron star. The documentary details the technical and social complications of building a generation ship to save humanity and other Earth organisms by relocating to a planet in another solar system.